# How do I plot this confusing multiple bar plot using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

As part of a larger data set, I have a column on banks (values being different names) and a column on mortgage status (values: Accepted; Declined). I'm having a lot of trouble creating a multiple bar plot that has the Banks as each x-value, and then two bars on each value for the # of accepted vs # of declined. Attaching a mock-up of what I want the end result to be, but am lost on how to get there. Do I need to use groupby?[Sample Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQoYF.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#bar-plots) or [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html) help you?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible source code so that people can help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick MVCE:

```
from seaborn import load_dataset
import pandas as pd

df_tip = load_dataset('tips')
print(df_tip.head())
```

Output of raw dataframe:

```
   total_bill   tip     sex smoker  day    time  size
0       16.99  1.01  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     2
1       10.34  1.66    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
2       21.01  3.50    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     3
3       23.68  3.31    Male     No  Sun  Dinner     2
4       24.59  3.61  Female     No  Sun  Dinner     4
```

Reshape your dataframe to look like this with your grouped bars as columns, and you x-axis as dataframe row indexes:

```
df_chart = df_tip.groupby(['day', 'sex'])['total_bill'].sum().unstack()
print(df_chart)
```

Output df_chart:

```
sex      Male  Female
day                  
Thur   561.44  534.89
Fri    198.57  127.31
Sat   1227.35  551.05
Sun   1269.46  357.70
```

Plot with pandas plot:

```
df_chart.plot.bar()
```

Chart:

[image]